# How to access from Linux (host) any content that needs the VPN connection running on Windows (guest)?

Tags: vpn, proxy, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, virtualbox

I'm working on a coding project that needs to access private URLs through a VPN connection.

The only way to connect to this VPN is through the company's proprietary software made only for Windows.

So, to work on this project we need to run Windows to connect to the VPN.

**I want to know if there is a way to actieve the following VM/network scenario:**

**1** - Linux as host.

**2** - Windows as guest.

**3** - On Windows I start the software to connect the VPN.

**4** - When Windows is connected to the VPN, I can browse private websites (e.g. "Private Website X") on Windows.

**5** - Linux would connect to the internet connection shared by Windows (maybe through a proxy or port fowarding, I don't know...)

**6** - On Linux I would open Firefox and browse all the private websites that I can browse in Windows.

[Here is a graphic to illustrate this scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3anf2.png)

**The main goal** is to access from Linux (host) any content that needs the VPN connection running on Windows (guest).

Comment: Came here to ask the same question.
Maybe would it be easier if the the VPN'd network would be accessible through another VM and not from the host? I know docker can use another container as a network so it could look a bit the same except that ideally you could do it with more than one VPN client. Unfortunately the docker solution basically bars using any Windows based client.

Comment: I am in the exact same situation and didn't find a solution yet! In my situation I have to access, let's say Private Website X, Private Website Y, Private Website Z. I tried nginx on guest (Network=Bridged Adapter) in order to map specific Private Websites URLs requests from host to guest, but this works for X, not Y and Z. Not the ideal solution. Did you get any progress in the meantime?